# Finding the n-th term in a sequence with no common ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series

I had this sequence `4,9,21,40,66,99,139` that i need to formulate a formula to find the n-th term. But my problem is that it doesn't have a common ratio and I can't find n-th term because of that.
This is the difference that I came up with it took 2 layers to have a common difference
[image]

Comment: **Hint:** look at the differences between successive terms.

Comment: Hint: If you get a common difference after **two** "layers", your function is of degree 2. You are looking for a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of layers it takes to get to a constant difference is the degree of the polynomial that produces the series.  Since you have two layers the terms fit a quadratic.  The leading coefficient is the difference divided by the factorial of the degree, so for you it is $\frac 7{2!}$.  Now you only have two more terms to find.  Use two of the values to find them.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this explains a lot. I'm sorry for this question, but may I ask what do you mean about use two of t he values to find them?

Comment: As you know it is a quadratic, the terms should fit $an^2+bn+c$.  I gave you $a$.  If you count the terms from $0$, the fact that the first is $4$ says $c=4$.  Now you can use the next term to evaluate $b$.  If you count the terms from $1$ it is more complicated, but you have two equations in two unknowns to evaluate $b$ and $c$.  Either way, you have a closed form expression for any term you want.  If you are asking this question, why did you accept the answer?  It clearly was not sufficient for what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this indeed is how i got it. And the way I got the 2nd coefficient is by using this formula a + b since I count the term from 0. And so I came up with this formula 7/2n^2+3/2n+4. This is it right?

Comment: It fits the first three numbers, so it has to be right.